# nginx - Serve multiple roots for different single page applications

Tags: nginx

I'm trying to serve two different versions of a single page application - one, built with a brand new, shiny JS framework, and another built with an older, crummier JS framework. All of the important features and functionality are in the new SPA, and all the non-critical in the older SPA and are in the midst of being ported over.

With this in mind, I'm trying to make the older SPA available via a path, e.g. `/old-app`.

The new app resides in `/www/new-app`.
The old app resides in `/www/old-app`.

This is what I have tried:

```
server {
  listen 443;

  root /www/new-app;
  index index.html;

  location / { # default to new app
    try_files $uri @prerender;
  }

  location /old-app {
    root /www/old-app; # I have also tried *alias* instead of *root* here
    index index.html;
    try_files $uri @prerender;
  }

  location @prerender {
    set $prerender = 0;

    # a bunch of rules for prerender from here: https://gist.github.com/thoop/8165802

    if ($prerender = 1) {
      proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080/$scheme://$host$request_uri;
    }

    if ($prerender = 0) {
      rewrite .* /index.html break;
    }
  }
}
```

The above returns a `200 OK` for `https://www.domain.example/old-app/<route>`, but the page served is not `/www/old-app/index.html`. Instead, the file served is from `/www/new-app/index.html` with a blank page, presumably because the new SPA does not understand the provided `/<route>`, which only the old SPA understands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things are wrong here.

```
location /old-app {
    root /www/old-app;
```

This will look for files at `/www/old-app/old-app` (see [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#root) for details).

```
try_files $uri @prerender;
```

This sends all of your routes to the `location @prerender` block, which ends with `rewrite .* /index.html break;`

There may be a more elegant solution, but you could just add a second "prerender" block, for example `location @oldrender` which is similar to the original, but ends with `rewrite ^ /old-app/index.html last;`

For example:

```
location /old-app {
    root /www;
    try_files $uri @oldrender;
}
location @oldrender {
    ...
        rewrite ^ /old-app/index.html last;
    ...
}
```

Notice the `root` has changed, and you need to use `rewrite...last`.

Comment: Thank you @Richard, that absolutely works! I've added my own answer to the question because I got it working before I had the chance to read your answer, but I will accept your answer as it is probably more correct than mine!

Answer (score 0):

While Richard's answer works and is probably more correct than mine, I ended up with the following config (before Richard had the chance to post his answer!) after a lot of trial and error. I'm posting it here for posterity, should anyone else have the same requirements as mine.

```
server {
  listen 443;

  root /www/new-app;
  index index.html;

  # I left the following alone
  location / {
    try_files $uri @prerender;
  }

  # Here's the meat of what worked
  location /old-app {
    alias /www/old-app;
    index index.html;
    try_files $uri $uri/ index.html;
  }
}
```

And finally, in the `index.html` of the old single page app, I added a `<base href="/old-app/" />` to make sure any references to images, stylesheets etc. were served from the correct server path.

Now, visiting `http://domain.example/old-app` correctly serves the default route of the old SPA!